# Giving data to other activity not working actually

Tags: android, android-activity

**What is the code about:** 
With my code I can open a mic, speak into it and see the output.

**Present Situation**  
Right now if I speak into the mic, I see the output and jump directly in other activity.

**Requirement** 
I want take the output in the activity but before I text to much I show you the code.

**Mainactivity.java**

```
private TextView voiceInput;
private ImageView speakButton;
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    voiceInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voiceInput);
    speakButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            askSpeechInput();
        }
    });
}

// Showing google speech input dialog

private void askSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Sprechen Sie was ein");
    //tent.putStringArrayListExtra("result",resultat);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(this,Zweites.class);
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("resultat",result);
                //ActivityZweites wird gestartet
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;
        }

    } }} <br>
```

In that I got the following problem:

```
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        //Ausgabe in andere Activity
        voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,Zweites.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("resultat",result);
        //ActivityZweites wird gestartet
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    break;
}
```

There it outputs the spoken input:

```
voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));
```

And afterwards it jumps into the activity. 
How can I get this output in the activity without first display the output and jump in another activity?

I tried some things but don´t come to a solution how to fix this problem. 
Do you guys got some ideas?

### Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to pass the same text to your intent that you're displaying in your TextView, exchange

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("resultat",result);
```

with

```
intent.putExtra("resultat", result.get(0));
```

Then, in your `Zweites` activity, you can get the string like so:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = intent.getStringExtra("resultat");
```